# How do you replace certain rows with text based on a condition from another column?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
                         Customer_order_table
    1desired_ship_date                                    Order_status
      2/5/2015                                              R
      2/10/2015                                             F
      2/12/2015                                             H 
      2/16/2015                                             R

   2desired_ship_date                                     Order_status
     2/5/2015                                               R
    'Not Sceduled'                                          F
    'Not Sceduled'                                          H
     2/16/2015                                              R
```

How do I get results like these through a query? I need to replace the date with something like 'Not scheduled' or it can just be blank if the order status is anything but R. The current results are first and the 2desired_ship_dates are the results I want. Thanks.

Comment: Why changing for `'Not Sceduled'` instead of using `NULL`?

Comment: Case when Order_Status = 'R' then Ship_date end

Comment: Null would work fine. I really just need the date to not show up.

Comment: @SeanLange You are assuming that the data type of the column is a string

Comment: @Lamak what other data type is going to hold R, F or H? The OP states they want the date only when the status is R.

Comment: @SeanLange I know, but we don't know if op is aware of that, that's why my first comment was to use `NULL` instead

Comment: The case function worked just fine. The data type for desired ship date is date/time so leaving it null makes things a lot easier.

Comment: I think you misread my comment @Lamak. I was using the status column NOT the date column in the case expression.

Comment: @SeanLange well, what do you know, I did read it wrong, sorry for that

Comment: The datatype for order_status is char(1)

Comment: heh I figured you did. No biggie, done it myself more times than I can count.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    co.customer_id, 
    co.ID as OrderID, 
    co.customer_po_ref,         
case 
when co.status = 'R' then co.desired_ship_date end as Releaseddate, 
   co.STATUS,
   co.sm_questions, 
   co.SM_CREDIT_HOLD, 
   co.SM_DESIGN   
from 
    dbo.customer_order as co
```

This script makes the ship date show up as blank if the order has not been released into production yet.